# To get the part of browser?

Tags: c#, regex

How can I get the part of a browser **url** user enter using regular expression Regex?

My url is like :

http://abc.com/weather/2013/9/5

How to get the Date part from this url and how to do the exception handling if user enter mistakenly like this:

http://abc.com/weather/2013/9/5/abc

Comment: What are the conditions of the expected format? Will it always be "/weather/year/month/day"? Might it be "/news/year/month/day"? "/news/international/year/month/day"? What indicates that "/weather/2013/9/6/abc" is an "error"? Should the last three parts always be the date?

Comment: "part of a browser"? A browser is Chrome, Firefox, IE, Safari, etc.

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Comment: @Snixtor: yes its "/weather/year/month/day" only for weather data but url can have other format to like "/news/year/month/day"
and also keep on mind user can change the url and post like 
"/weather/year/month/day/<Anything>"
Barmar: sorry for typos,
JohnSaunders: I have tried to get using : (http(s?)://[^/]+/)
so far not good

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like

```
"[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}"

http://abc.com/weather/2013/9/5 = "2013/9/5"
http://abc.com/weather/2013/9/5/abc = "2013/9/5"
http://abc.com/weather/2013/11/21/abc = "2013/11/21"
```

Comment: What about days or months with 2 digits?

Comment: I will try this method let you know ;)